# python/pandas - expected a simple type, a tuple or a list

Tags: python, pandas, azure, databricks, azure-databricks

We have a following `notebook` in [Azure Databricks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/scenarios/what-is-azure-databricks#:%7E:text=Azure%20Databricks%20is%20a%20data,Microsoft%20Azure%20cloud%20services%20platform.&text=For%20a%20big%20data%20pipeline,Event%20Hub%2C%20or%20IoT%20Hub.) that gives the error shown below:

> expected a simple type, a tuple or a list

**Question**: What could be a cause of the error and can we fix it?

**Remarks**: We are using pandas' `to-datetime(...)` to convert the relevant fields to datetime. But the error occurs at the function call to: `pandas_df.to_sql(.....)` in the code below.

**code**:

```
import sqlalchemy as sq
import datetime
import pandas as pd

pw = dbutils.secrets.get(scope='SomeScope',key='sql')
engine = sq.create_engine('mssql+pymssql://SERVICE.Databricks.NONPUBLICETL:'+pw+'MyAzureSQL.database.windows.net:1433/TEST', isolation_level="AUTOCOMMIT")

 pandas_df = pd.read_sql('select * from SQLTable1', con=engine)

pandas_df['Field2_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(pandas_df['Field2_Date'])
pandas_df['Field4_Date']= pd.to_datetime(pandas_df['Field4_Date'])
.............
...............
pandas_df['Field11_Date'] = datetime.date.today


pandas_df.to_sql(name='SQLTable2', con=engine, if_exists='replace', index=False, dtype={'Field1' : sq.NVARCHAR(50),\
'Field2_Date' : sq.DATETIME,\
'Field3' : sq.NVARCHAR(50),\
'Field4_Date' : sq.DATETIME(),\
'Field5' : sq.NVARCHAR(50),\
'Field6_Date' : sq.DATETIME(),\
'Field7_Amount' : sq.FLOAT(),\
'Field8' : sq.INT(),\
'Field11_Date' : sq.DATE() })
```

**Detailed error**:

```
ValueError: expected a simple type, a tuple or a list
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-....> in <module>
      
      
---> pandas_df.to_sql(name='SQLTable2', con=engine, if_exists='replace', index=False, dtype={'Field1' : sq.NVARCHAR(50),\
                                                                                                                        'Field2_Date' : sq.DATETIME(),\
                                                                                                                        'Field3' : sq.NVARCHAR(50),\

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in to_sql(self, name, con, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype, method)
            from pandas.io import sql
    
->          sql.to_sql(
                self,
                name,

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in to_sql(frame, name, con, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype, method)
    403         )
    404 
--> 405     pandas_sql.to_sql(
    406         frame,
```

Comment: Just for the record, none of those backslashes are necessary.  Once you are inside a set of parentheses, you can extend the statement as much as you want to.

Comment: You have `sq.DATETIME` where you wanted `sq.DATETIME()`.  That's the cause of the error: it got a function where it wanted an object.

Comment: @TimRoberts After reading your comment, I changed it to `sq.DATETIME()` but still the exact same error. I also verified that the other data types have parenthesis at the end: sq.FLOAT(), sq.INT() etc. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Show us the whole traceback.  There are always useful details beyond just the error message.

Comment: @TimRoberts I just added the details under **Detailed error** section at the end.

Comment: You have `datetime.date.today`  -- again, that passed a function where an object is expected.  You need `datetime.date.today()`.  And because you omitted the other lines, we can't verify those.

Comment: @TimRoberts Your suggestion**s** worked (thank you). +1

Answer (score 0):

> expected a simple type, a tuple or a list

One of the workaround to solve the above issue,
Thank you @Tim Roberts, Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members ,

"As you have `datetime.date.today` which passed a function so an object is expected. Instead of that we can use `datetime.date.today()` ."

For more information please refer the below links:

BLOG: [***pymssql: executemany value error - expected a simple type, a tuple or a list***](https://www.py4u.net/discuss/209909) & [***Tuple and sequence in python***](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)